# How to refresh pivot table in Apache POI without opening the file on updating the data source?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I tried below code but it only works when I open the file manually.

```
pivotCacheDefinition.getCTPivotCacheDefinition().setRefreshOnLoad(true);
```

Comment: "only works when I open the file manually": Yes that is exactly what `setRefreshOnLoad` means. Apache POI does not rendering pivot tables. So no way to get a refreshed pivot table without opening in Excel.

Comment: @AxelRichter Actually I am updating the Data source and want to reflect the updated data in pivot table and fetch it but when i fetch the data from pivot it shows previous data only. How can I do it? Any help?

Comment: As said already: No way to do this using Apache POI. Apache POI does not rendering pivot tables. It only updates the building instructions of the pivot tables as only those are stored in the Excel files. The building of the pivot tables according to the stored instructions gets done in Excel GUI only.